# EWS managed-api encountered 500 internal server error when import EML

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

When I import a large mail filer via ews-managed api, it encountered http code 500 with reponse:

```
Cache-Control: private^M
Content-Length: 1015^M
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8^M
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 03:03:01 GMT^M
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error^M
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0^M
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=12133ae873f24a8f80b93e5b92ab3979; 
expires=Fri, 20-Sep-2019 03:01:27 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly^M
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319^M
X-BEServer: PS2PR02MB2694^M
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 500^M
X-BeSku: WCS5^M
X-CalculatedBETarget: PS2PR02MB2694.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com^M
X-CalculatedFETarget: PS2P216CU002.internal.outlook.com^M
X-DiagInfo: PS2PR02MB2694^M
X-FEProxyInfo: PS2P216CA0031.KORP216.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM^M
X-FEServer: HK0PR03CA0085^M
X-FEServer: PS2P216CA0031^M
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-RUM-Validated: 1
request-id: 905db567-dcf7-449c-820d-b00ed0afa981
x-ms-appId: af08ce07-1df9-4a39-b6e6-092ac934eb21
```

However, the mail was successfully uploaded.

It should be a mismatch error code, or something wrong in this request.

Should I retry this request again? or anyway to improve this behavior?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it your own server or are you using Office 365?

Comment: Hi Simon, I am using Office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your setting the X-AnchorMailbox header to the Mailbox your importing to otherwise the backend servers will be proxying the request on you behalf so you can get that type of error for long running operations when the server doesn't receive the response in time (the state of the operation at that point is unknown).